# Create React App PWA ERROR: Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to create a progressive web app with Create React App, but I get an error when I benchmark with lighthouse. My pwa is not unstalable, what is strange is that I have the same problem if I use the official pwa template from cra.

I tried to change the start url to the domain name of my app but it doesn't work

I get this error:

```
Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url
```

and

```
Web app manifest or service worker do not meet the installability requirements 1 reason
```

I don't understand why I get this error because I've followed exactly the documentation

Here is my config :

manifest.json

```
{
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "short_name": "test",
  "name": "test",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/android/android-launchericon-512-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/android/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/android/maskable_icon_x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

service-worker.ts

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

clientsClaim()

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$')
registerRoute(
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false
    }
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false
    }
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false
    }

    // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.
    return true
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/index.html`)
)

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) =>
    url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'),
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
)

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting()
  }
})
```

serviceWorkerRegistration.ts

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
)

type Config = {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void
}

export function register(config?: Config): void {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href)
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config)
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA'
          )
        })
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config)
      }
    })
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config): void {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See https://cra.link/PWA.'
              )
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration)
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.')

              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    })
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: Config): void {
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload()
          })
        })
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config)
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      )
    })
}

export function unregister(): void {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message)
      })
  }
}
```

app.tsx

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()
```

workbox version: 6.1.5

Comment: so, all you do is `unregister` - you never `register`?

Comment: @JaromandaX   Why would you unregister if it is a PWA?

Comment: @nywooz - not my code, not my problem

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to register the service worker, thanks !

I change

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()
```

to

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.register()
```